# MPMoviePlayerController getting deallocated at play() - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an `MPMoviePlayerController` to a view controller but it is getting deallocated right at the `play()` call. The URL is valid when it is printed, I am also using a nearly identical piece of code in a different `viewController` and it works perfectly fine. The only difference between the view controllers is that this one was segued to from a different `viewController`. I have been racking my brain on this and tried all the similar solutions I could find on here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Prepare for Segue**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowChannel" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ShowChannelController {
            destination.channelId = channelId
            destination.postsCollection = postsCollection
        }
    }
}
```

**MPMoviePlayerController code**

```
var newMoviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!
var postsCollection = [Post]()
var videoPosition = 0
var channelId: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    startPlayingVideo(videoPosition)
    updateNowPlaying(videoPosition)
    
} 

func videoHasFinishedPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
    /* Find out what the reason was for the player to stop */
    let reason =
    notification.userInfo![MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey]
        as! NSNumber?
    if let theReason = reason{
        
        let reasonValue = MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: theReason.integerValue)

        stopPlayingVideo()
        
        switch reasonValue!{
        case .PlaybackEnded:
            if (videoPosition < self.postsCollection.count - 1) {
                videoPosition++
            } else {
                videoPosition = 0
            }
            startPlayingVideo(videoPosition)
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: videoPosition, inSection: 0);
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
            updateNowPlaying(videoPosition)
            
        case .PlaybackError:
            /* An error happened and the movie ended */
            print("Error happened")
        case .UserExited:
            /* The user exited the player */
            print("User exited")
        }
        
    }
    
}

/** What to do when we stop playing a video */
func stopPlayingVideo() {
    if let player = self.newMoviePlayer {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        player.stop()
        player.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
}

/** Initializes and starts the video player */
func startPlayingVideo(index: Int) {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: postsCollection[index].url)!
    print(postsCollection[index].url)
    self.newMoviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    if let player = self.newMoviePlayer {
        
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "videoHasFinishedPlaying:", name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, object: nil)
        
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: ((self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.45) - (self.view.bounds.size.height / 3)), width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height / 3)
        
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
        
    } else {
        print("Failed to instantiate the movie player")
    }
    
}
```

**Error:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_xpc_dictionary _postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ed2240'

**Zombie Enabled:**

> -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17f47400**

Comment: Do you really want to do it in viewDidLoad or can I go into viewDidAppear? Assuming issue still persists there, here is what you can do to debug: subclass MPMoviePlayerController and use that in your code.  Set a breakpoint in your new subclass's dealloc and see what causes it to be deallocated.

Comment: @Boon I changed it to the viewDidAppear which made no difference in the crash, but I did just find the solution 1 min ago I'll post it.

Comment: Cool, it may still be the right place to do things though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally realized my error:**

The first ViewController mentioned that had a similar implementation, and was working fine, did not properly dispose of the 'NotificationCenter' and the observers in the two seperate classes were getting confused.

**Solution:**

remove observer in first `ViewController`'s `viewDidDisappear()`

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Lesson learned: Don't forget to unregister yourself!